# How to use an ActiveModel with resourceful URL helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, activemodel

A confusing question title requiring a lot of explanation for what I hope isn't actually too difficult a problem.

I have created a little ActiveModel (`FooBarSearch`) to handle search requests for an ActiveRecord model (`FooBar`) in my Rails 3.2.16 application. There are a few places in the site I would like my users to be able to search `FooBar` so I want to be able to use URL helpers, but I am having trouble getting it all working.

I suspect the issue is me having to define some sort of `to_param` or `to_query` method in `FooBarSearch`. But can not find a definitive solution or guide. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### What I want to be able to write

```
- @request = FooBarSearch.new :option => 'value'
= link_to 'download csv', search_foo_bar_path(@request, :format => :csv)
```

### What this currently produces

```
<a href="/foo_bar/search">download csv</a>
```

### What I want to see

The following is what I see in the address bar in Chrome when the form submits, and so (I assume) this is what I want the URL helper to produce

```
<a href="/foo_bar/search.csv?utf8=✓&foo_bar_search%5Boption_1%5D=value&foo_bar_search%5Boption_2%5D=value_2&commit=Search">
```

---

### Edit

After a lot of keyboard bashing i seem to have come up with something that works as i detailed above. The only problem is i don't really know *why* it works? Can anyone explain?

### app/models/concerns/foo_bar_search.rb

```
  def attributes
    { :option_1 => @option_1, :option_2 => @option_2, :option_3 => @option_3 }
  end

  def to_param
    attributes.to_param
  end

  def to_query(key = 'foo_bar_request')
    attributes.to_query(key)
  end
```

---

### Existing code

### /app/controllers/foo_bars_controller.rb

```
class FooBarController < ApplicationController
  def
    if params[:foo_bar_search]
      @request = FooBarSearch.new params[:for_bar_search]
    else
      @request = FooBarSearch.new
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { @request.to_csv }
    end
  end
end
```

### /app/views/foo_bars/search.html.haml

```
%h1= @page_title = "Foo Bar Search"

= form_for(@request, :url => search_foo_bar_path, :method => :get) do |f|
  .form_section
    %table
      %tr
        %th Search Option 1
        %td= f.select :some_option_id
    = submit_tag 'Search!'
```

### config/routes.rb

```
  resources :foo_bar do
    collection do
      get :search
      post :search
    end
  end
```

### app/models/concerns/foo_bar_search.rb

```
class FooBarSearch
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  # Required by ActiveModel::Conversion
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def initialize(options = {})
    # ...
  end

  # I think i may need #to_param and/or #to_query here, 
  # but so far have not been able to get this working...
end
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try this
`= link_to search_foo_bar_path(:foo_bar_search=>params[:foo_bar_search], :format => :csv)` Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Yes i think that would work (will check) on `/foo_bars/search.html.haml` but I want to be able to use that anywhere, hence wanting to pass the `FooBarSearch.new` object to the URL helper

Comment: I am not totally understandg ideally,but you can Create partial and render as per your requirement so partial is aform for search.html.haml

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to write `link_to search_foo_bar_path(@request, :format => :csv)` in any view and not have to look at the params. I think i need to define `to_param` and/or `to_query` but i am not sure

Comment: I think you can try to_param

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and may be able to shed some light.

View the source on [ActiveModel::Conversion#to_param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_param). See how it already defines `to_param` for you, and returns the object's key, but only if `persisted?` returns true.

Your `to_param` definition includes `:id` (and all of the other irrelevant attributes) even though `persisted?` is hardcoded to `false`. This explains why it works for you, but your override isn't really correct.

To solve my similar problem, I defined persisted as:

```
# assume object is persisted if it has an id
def persisted?
  self.id.present?
end
```

Also, you may want to check out the Platformatec blog on [Barebone models to use with ActionPack in Rails 4.0](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/03/barebone-models-to-use-with-actionpack-in-rails-4-0/). If you `include ActiveModel::Model`, it takes care of including the other ActiveModel modules you're using, the `initialize` and `persisted?` methods and other goodies, so all you'll need to do is override `persisted?` as I described.

Thanks for your question! It helped me connect the dots with my own issue.